# Load view error codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in codeigniter. I want to save something database.
I have link localhost/index.php/blog/gerilim_controller/40
I want to save 40 to database.

I wrote some code. This is my model code: Akim_model.php;

```
<?php
class Akim_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
    }

    function ekle($data)
        {
          $ekle=$this->db->insert('gerilim',$data); 
          if($ekle){
         return 1;
        }else{
         return 0;
        }
        }
}
?>
```

This is my controllers code: Blog.php;

```
 <?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

        public function index()
        {
                $this->load->helper('url');     }

    public function gerilim_controller( $gerilim_id = NULL ) {
        echo $gerilim_id;
        $data=array('gerilim'=>$this->input->post('gerilim'));
            $this->load->model('akim_model');
            $sonuc=$this->akim_model->ekle($data);
            if($sonuc==1)
              echo "Successed"; 
           else
              echo "Failed";
    }


}
?>
```

But when `$this->load->model('akim_model');` its gives an error. Where I am wrong?

Comment: what is the error?where is the `akim_model` ?why did you give different name `Site_model` ??

Comment: What is the error

Comment: your file akim_model should contain a class "akim_model

Comment: I checked them.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Blog::$site_model

Filename: controllers/Blog.php

Line Number: 27

Backtrace:

File: /home/lebturkey/public_html/application/controllers/Blog.php
Line: 27
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/lebturkey/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Not all... You have a link like /blog/get_gerilim/40. It appears you only have a method called  gerilim_controller (Very Bad Name... why have _controller?). There is No get_gerilim method... So please fix that.

Comment: @user3748265 can you post real code? how can you call a model that does't exist  `$sonuc=$this->site_model->ekle($gerilim_id);`.it should be `akim_model` not `site_model`

Comment: I checked that. and corrected that. Stil I have an error 
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'gerilim' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `gerilim` (`gerilim`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: models/Akim_model.php

Line Number: 12

Comment: @user3748265 that's not what you asked ?avoid change question too much

Answer (score 0):

THe file name must match the class name for your model:

```
<?php
  class Akim_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->database();
    }

    function ekle($data) {
      $ekle=$this->db->insert('gerilim',$data); 
      if($ekle) {
        return 1;
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Also put your conditional statement in curly braces:

```
    if($sonuc==1) {
      echo "Successed"; 
    }
    else {
      echo "Not successed";
    }
```

You should call your model using the class name:

```
$this->akim_model->ekle($data);
```

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'gerilim' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `gerilim` (`gerilim`) VALUES (NULL)

Filename: models/Akim_model.php

Line Number: 12

Comment: Please remove `NULL` from this line you can set it to empty `public function gerilim_controller( $gerilim_id = NULL )` to `public function gerilim_controller( $gerilim_id ='')`

Comment: Also change this  `$data=array('gerilim'=>$this->input->post('gerilim'));` to `$data= array('gerilim'=>$gerilim_id);` since you didn't say you are submitting to the controller from a POST form